# Paginate How to return all rows but start at condition

Tags: laravel

This is my current query. It works great except that the first result never has a `prev_page_url` because it is grabbing  rows `>=` to the id. Is there anyway to modify the current query to also return the row before?

I know I can paginate more results but I don't want to return more than one result at a time if I dont have to because I am only displaying one result at a time on the frontend

```
$display = DB::connection('mysql')
    ->table('queue')
    ->where('ID', '>=', $id)
    ->paginate(1);
```

Comment: You are specifying a where clause, so the "1st" page will always be >= id. You need to pass the correct page number if you wish to include previous results.

Comment: How would I pass the page number? I only have 3 columns in my table `id`, `name`, `info` and I need to return results based on the last ID the user stopped at so they can properly navigate to the next page using buttons

Comment: pass `page=X` in your query string.

Comment: Do you mean pass back a custom query string to the back end?